# How can I add every value with the same key together in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add every value with the same key togehter.
The Arrays look something like this, only with different values:

```
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
{"bank":1752000,"money":215560,"black_money":0}
```

As the result in the end i need three variables. One for bank, one for money and one for black_money. Can somebody please help me, i tried a lot of ways but none of theme worked.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < allplayercount; i++) {
      console.log(result[i]['accounts'].bank);
    }` So i tried to loop over every array and get the "bank"-values to add them later together.

Comment: Try this: `const sumOfObj = arr => arr.reduce((f, i) => ({bankSum: f.bankSum + i.bank, moneySum: f.moneySum + i.money, blackMoneySum: f.blackMoneySum + i['black_money']}), {bankSum: 0, moneySum: 0, blackMoneySum: 0}); const {bankSum, moneySum, blackMoneySum} = sumOfObj(arr); console.log('bank: ', bankSum, '\t money: ', moneySum, '\t black_money', blackMoneySum);`

Comment: @jsN00b please don't answer in the comments.  Comments don't have editing tools, cannot be upvoted/downvoted/removed the same way as answers.

Comment: Apologies - it was not meant to be an answer. It's just something for OP to try. The implied intention was to share their feedback (& hopefully ask questions on why it fails or if it gets them their desired result). While my hope is that it does meet the OPs objective, it is not an answer - as I haven't put the effort to offer an explanation that an answer deserves. Hence, left it as a comment. Happy to delete - if that's preferred, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise an object with default values, and then loop over the array, and add each object property value to the output object.

```js
const data = [
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 },
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 },
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 },
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 },
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 },
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 },
  { bank: 1752000, money: 215560, black_money: 0 }
];

const out = { bank: 0, money: 0, black_money: 0 };

for (const obj of data) {
  out.bank += obj.bank;
  out.money += obj.money;
  out.black_money += obj.black_money;
}

console.log(out);
console.log(out.bank);
console.log(out.money);
console.log(out.black_money);
```